# When using SwiftUI, how can one add a consistent styled "Add" button at the end of a flow layout?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have currently achieved a flow layout for a group of tags, as shown in Figure 1. However, when attempting to add an "Add" button at the end of the flow layout in a consistent manner, it does not properly align at the end. I desire it to appear as illustrated in Figure 2.
Below is the layout code and the custom struct for the flow layout. I appreciate your assistance greatly.

```
VStack (
    //alignment: .leading
){
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("✖️")
            Spacer() 
            Button(action: {
                showCategoryPopUp.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
        WrappingHStack(models: firstCategories, viewGenerator: { category in
            Group {
                Text(category.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .black, design: .default))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10) 
                    .padding(.vertical, 5) 
                    .frame(minWidth: 60) 
                    //.background(Color.green) 
                    .background(selectedFirstCategoryID == category.id ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedFirstCategoryID == category.id ? .white : .black)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle()) 
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedFirstCategoryID = category.id
                    }
                    .shake(animatableData: isShaking ? 1 : 0)
                    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
                        print("Long press detected for category: \(category.name)")
                        isShaking.toggle()
                        showDeleteIcon.toggle()
                    }
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        if isShaking {
                            isShaking = false
                            showDeleteIcon = false
                        }
                    })
            }
        })
        //.padding()
        HStack {
            Text("➕")
                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .black, design: .default))
                //.padding(.horizontal, 10) 
                .padding(.vertical, 5) 
                .frame(minWidth: 60)
                .background(Color.gray) 
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .contentShape(Rectangle()) 
                .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Add new category")
                }
            Spacer()
        }

    }
```

```
struct WrappingHStack<Model, V>: View where Model: Hashable, V: View {
    typealias ViewGenerator = (Model) -> V
    var models: [Model]
    var viewGenerator: ViewGenerator
    var horizontalSpacing: CGFloat = 5
    var verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 5

    @State private var totalHeight
          = CGFloat.zero       // << variant for ScrollView/List
    //    = CGFloat.infinity   // << variant for VStack
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                self.generateContent(in: geometry)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: totalHeight)// << variant for ScrollView/List
        //.frame(maxHeight: totalHeight) // << variant for VStack
    }

    private func generateContent(in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        var width = CGFloat.zero 
        var height = CGFloat.zero 
        let addButton = Text("➕")
            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .black, design: .default))
            .padding(.horizontal, 10) 
            .padding(.vertical, 5) 
            //.frame(minWidth: minLabelWidth, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) 
            .frame(minWidth: 60)
            .background(Color.gray) 
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) 
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Add new category")
            }

        return ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach(self.models, id: \.self) { model in
                viewGenerator(model) 
                    .padding(.horizontal, horizontalSpacing) 
                    .padding(.vertical, verticalSpacing) 
                    .alignmentGuide(.leading) { dimension in 
                        if (abs(width - dimension.width) > geometry.size.width) {
                            width = 0 
                            height -= dimension.height 
                        }
                        let result = width 
                        if model == self.models.last! {
                            width = 0 
                        } else {
                            width -= dimension.width 
                        }
                        return result 
                    }
                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in 
                        let result = height 
                        if model == self.models.last! {
                            height = 0 
                        }
                        return result 
                    }
            }
        
            addButton
                //.offset(CGSize(width: horizontalSpacing, height: verticalSpacing))
        }
        .background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight)) 
    }
    private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
            }
            return .clear
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpktr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXCAD.png)

Comment: Please, add a minimal reproducible example that you can copy and paste in a blan project: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does [this package](https://github.com/tevelee/SwiftUI-Flow) help?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).